# liquibase update where with LIKE clause

Tags: liquibase

I want to add ***LIKE*** clause to liquibase update. Have done something like that, but it seems to be not working properly:

```
    <changeSet id="LoremIpsum" author="JohnDoe">
    <update tableName="table_for_John_Doe">
        <column name="id" value="000001"/>
        <where>
            from LIKE :first OR
            from LIKE :second OR
            to LIKE :first OR
            to LIKE :second
        </where>
        <whereParams>
            <param name="first" value="TEST1"/>
            <param name="second" value="TEST2"/>
        </whereParams>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

I tried adding ***`''`*** but again no expected results. If it should be working so maybe I have made a mistake somewhere else.

Should I write native sql query instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the *whereParams* incorrectly. 
Have a look here: [LiquiBase : How to use <whereparams> inside an <update>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941373/liquibase-how-to-use-whereparams-inside-an-update)

For a table like this:

| id | name | column_to_update |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA |  |
| 2 | AB |  |
| 3 | BA |  |
| 3 | CA |  |

The change set, for example to update all rows, where name starts with A or C, should look like this:

```
    <changeSet id="LoremIpsum" author="JohnDoe">
        <update tableName="table_for_John_Doe">
            <column name="column_to_update" value="000001"/>
            <where>
                 :name LIKE :value or
                 :name LIKE :value 
            </where>
            <whereParams>
                <param name="name" value="A%"/>
                <param name="name" value="C%"/>
            </whereParams>
        </update>
    </changeSet>
```